# I'm trying to load JavaScript into my UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to load JavaScript into a UIWebView. Below is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:request];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    NSString *javascript = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"script.js" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  The web view finishes loading, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the Javascript.

Comment: Looks like it probably won't know where to find script.js. If you replace `@"script.js"` with `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"script" ofType:@"js"]`, does that help at all?

Comment: No, that didn't work :(  I'm still getting a blank web view

Comment: Two more things to check: 1) is `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` getting called? If not, you may not have the web view's delegate outlet set. 2) Is script.js included in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase?

Comment: And if all else fails, can you post the contents of script.js? That might help shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to load JavaScript into the UIWebView. [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString] is used to execute a function that's already loaded in the UIWebView.

Why aren't you including script.js in your local index.html file, and then calling a function defined in script.js using [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString]?

Let me know If I mis-understood your question.

Comment: I actually solved this problem yesterday and forgot to close this question.  You do understand correctly however.  The problem I was having was that I forgot to put my .js files in my resource bundle.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello there!!
>
> Here is my answer.Its my working code. Create a JSLibraries physical
>   folder in your project workspace.Add it to your project.copy your
>   abc.js file to it.

```
 - (void) addJSLibraryToHTML
{
    NSURL *jqueryLibPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"abc" withExtension:@"js" subdirectory:@"/JSLibraries" ];
    NSString *offlineJqueryLib = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"function addJquery()"
                                  "{"
                                  "function loadScript(url, callback)"
                                  "{"
                                  "var script = document.createElement('script');"
                                  "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
                                  "script.onload = function () {"
                                  "callback();"
                                  "};"
                                  "script.src = url;"
                                  "(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);"
                                  "}"
                                  "if(window.jQuery===undefined)"
                                  "{"
                                  "loadScript('%@', function ()"
                                  "{"
                                  "//do call back to your native method from here"
                                  "});"
                                  "}"
                                  "} ; addJquery();",jqueryLibPath.absoluteString];
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:offlineJqueryLib];
}
```